# Stem words with Keras tokenizer

Tags: keras

Using Keras tokenizer (https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/#tokenizer), I would like to apply some transformation on words:

- lowercase
- asciifolding
- steming
- synonym (u => you etc..)
- gooood => good (dont know the name of this one)

(exactly how elasticsearch/lucene do, with analysis filters).

Comment: When would you want to apply these transformations? It seems like you can do them prior to using Keras as a sensitisation step before running tokenizer.

Comment: I want to use the Keras Tokenizer function, exactly like Apache Lucene does, tokenize then apply filtering. Just wondering if this is something common with Keras or not